# MikTeX asking to install package, but failing to do so

Tags: pdftex, packages, miktex

I am having problems with my new MikTeX setup on windows 10. Note before starting that the install is completely fresh.
Further, I want to note that MikTeX is set to ask for permission to install missing packages.
Now, to the core of the problem.
Whenever I try to compile my document, I will get the following message:

```
[Compiling C:\Users\[...]\Documents\[...]\Tex Files\main.tex]

    TraditionalBuilder: Engine: pdflatex. Invoking texify...
```

A few seconds later, MikTeX will ask for permission to install the missing packages, which it is set to get from a random package repo.
After agreeing to it, the window will close and, after a few more seconds, I get the following error message.

```
Errors:

C:\Program Files\MikTeX\tex\latex\lipsum\lipsum.sty:28: LaTeX Error: File `expl3.sty' not found. [\RequirePackage{expl3}[2018/10/31]]
```

Afterwards, I would go into MikTeX Console and try to install the package manually, which would work without fail (note that I did this multiple times, for multiple packages). The error occurs whether it is allowed to install on the fly or is supposed to ask beforehand. Also, I never had a problem with a server not being available and my internet connection works perfectly.

I don't know where MikTeX is supposed to be installed by default, but I installed it in the Program Files folder, so maybe it is a permissions problem, however I did not manage to figure out how to solve it if it were.

Thanks in advance for your help,

EDIT: I created a local repository to exclude the possibility of a connectivity issue, and indeed, the connectivity is not the problem.

Comment: which editor do you use?

Comment: I use sublime text.

Comment: Look in the package manager for some package you don't have, create a document and compile on the command line to check if on-the-fly works there.

Answer (score 1):

Re-install MiKTeX and don't update. Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: So, what did it in the end for me was restarting my editor (sublime text) in administrator mode. Then and only then does MikTeX manage to download packages on the fly.